# I want to get minimum of starttime of each id. But I'm not able to achieve it using min function. How to solve it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

Table:

```
    id | starttime  | grade
    -------------------------
     1 | 4PM        | A
     1 | 5PM        | C
     2 | 2PM        | A
     2 | 3PM        | B
```

In output I should get all the ids that have minimum starttime with all the columns.
For the above table output should be like this:

```
 id | starttime  | grade
-------------------------
  1 | 4PM        | A
  2 | 2PM        | A
```

Comment: Why not add some rows to your sample data, at least one more with the minimum starttime? And also specify the expected result.

Comment: Why can't you use `min`? Seems like a simple group by query to me...

Comment: What is the data type of `starttime`?  The assumption is that it is a time, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: You can of course use the min function and group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the minimum `starttime` for each `id`.

```
select top (1) with ties *
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by starttime);
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RJVT1405

returns:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | starttime | grade |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | 4PM       | A     |
|  2 | 2PM       | A     |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, use `top with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by starttime;
```

`TOP (1)` only returns one row.  `TOP (1) WITH TIES` returns all rows that have the same key value as in the first row specified by the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: This is going to return only a row, but he says he wants "all" the ids having minimum starttime.

Comment: @MarcGuillot You might want to refresh on how [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) works. Gordon's query will return all rows that have the single lowest value for `starttime`.

Comment: Actually, your current query with the current sample data will return only one row - SqlZim's query will return the correct data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Question sample data was changed after this was posted. Based on the wording of the original question and the original sample data, this answer was correct.

Comment: @SqlZim No it wasn't correct even then. Sample data had (and still have) a single record at 2pm - that's the only record that would return in both cases. Your answer is correct because it's ordered by row_number per id. Even the best of us can get it wrong sometimes.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I guess it depends on if you consider the title of the question the question or the body of the question the question. They differ between "all the ids that have minimum starttime" and "minimum of starttime of each id". I'd say both answers are 50% correct ^.^

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could say that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by:

```
with minTimes (id, startTime) as 
(
  select id, min(startTime) from myTable
  group by id
)
select t1.*
from myTable t1 
inner join minTimes t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.startTime = t2.startTime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;WITH cte(id,starttime, grade)
 AS
 (
 SELECT 1 , '4PM','A' Union all
 SELECT 1 , '5PM','C' Union all
 SELECT 2 , '2PM','A' Union all
 SELECT 2 , '3PM','B'
 )

,Final AS (
    SELECT *
        ,Row_Number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY MinStartTime ORDER BY MinStartTime
            ) Seq
    FROM (
        SELECT id
            ,CAST(starttime AS TIME) AS starttime
            ,MIN(CAST(starttime AS TIME)) OVER (
                PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY starttime
                ) AS MinStartTime
            ,grade
        FROM cte
        ) Dt
    )

SELECT id
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), MinStartTime, 100) AS starttime
    ,grade
FROM final
WHERE Seq = 1
ORDER BY 1
```